# mail sent with php's mail() has blank From field

Tags: php, email

I'm sending email with PHP's mail function.
It works just as it should except all email clients show blank From-field.
Here's how i'm using the function:

```
mail( 'mail@example.com', 'Example subject', $msg, 
       implode( '\r\n', array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: test@example.com') ) );
```

As i said everything works fine except From field is all blank when the message arrives.
Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This code would produce a parse error. Can you show please a real code?

Comment: ah yeah sorry had to edit it a bit. secret stuff you know .)
should work now

Comment: So, what's the result of this edited code?

Comment: Try do the implode out of mail function and save it a variable and us that variable in mail function

Comment: '\r\n' will not work, you have to put it in "\r\n", so it interpolates.

Comment: @wishcow, ok thanx. didn't know that one. tho still missing from-fields.

Comment: I changed position of "From"-string in imploded array (moved it as first) and now i get correct From-field in emails.
But the problem is that now it messes up the body of my emails. Strange line breaks (over 10 rows) suddenly appeared.
this is weird.

Comment: Try this format 'From: Nikkeloodeni <Nikkeloodeni@example.com>'

Comment: tried that format but still no luck.
Either the from field is completely missing or the body is scribbled the way it should not be. argh!

Comment: Please can you let us know what mail server you are using? sendmail or postfix or something else? also, if you know the version number of the mail server it would also help.

Comment: why use implode for mail function @Nikkeloodeni

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

> **Against Your idea**
>   Check this what you get

```
  <?php 
    $implode =implode( "\r\n", array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: test@example.com') );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($implode);
    ?>
```

Comment: This works indeed, but i still can't get it why my version doesn't include From header? I tried to add X-Mailer and Reply-To headers, too, but still no From-field in sent emails.

Comment: Try do the implode out of mail function and save it a variable and us that variable in mail function

Comment: did u used a separate variable in mail function for implode?

Comment: this is what i got:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
From: test@example.com

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote before your "Content-Type" and probably have error logging turned way down so it's ignoring the problem and getting all confused with parsing your code.

Should be:

```
mail( 'mail@example.com', "Example subject", $msg, 
       implode( "\r\n", array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: test@example.com') ) );
```